# Mongoose delete other objects after update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble with my update query on mongoose. I'm not sure why other objects get deleted after I update a specific object. the code works when I update but after that, the rest of the objects inside the array are getting deleted/removed. Literally, all of the remaining objects get deleted after the update request.

```
export const updateProduct = async (req,res) => {
     const { id } = req.params;
 
     try {
         if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Invalid ID' });
 
         await OwnerModels.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': id, store:{$elemMatch: {productname: req.body.store[0].productname }}},
             {$set: 
                 {
                     store: 
                         {
                             productname: req.body.store[0].productname,
                             price: req.body.store[0].price,
                             quantity: req.body.store[0].quantity,
                             categoryfilter: req.body.store[0].categoryfilter,
                             description: req.body.store[0].description,
                             timestamp: req.body.store[0].timestamp                        
                         }
                 }
         }, // list fields you like to change
         {'new': true, 'safe': true, 'upsert': true});
 
     } catch (error) {
         res.status(404).json(error)
     } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure why other objects get deleted after I update a specific object.

Because you are updating the whole object and it will replace the existing store array of object in the database,

You need to use arraFilters, and `upsert` is not effective in array of object updated, so i have commented,

```
await OwnerModels.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        '_id': id, 
        store:{
            $elemMatch: {
                productname: req.body.store[0].productname 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            store: {
                "store.$[s].productname": req.body.store[0].productname,
                "store.$[s].price": req.body.store[0].price,
                "store.$[s].quantity": req.body.store[0].quantity,
                "store.$[s].categoryfilter": req.body.store[0].categoryfilter,
                "store.$[s].description": req.body.store[0].description,
                "store.$[s].timestamp": req.body.store[0].timestamp
            }
        }
    },
    {
        'arrayFilters': [
            { "s.productname": req.body.store[0].productname }
        ],
        'new': true, 
        'safe': true, 
        // 'upsert': true
    }
);
```

Comment: I tried to use dot notation. it's giving me status 404 error ..well idk why. I'm checking the req.body it seems it's working well..

Comment: Please provide the full error stack, 404 does not help to understand the problem.

Comment: MongoServerError: Cannot create field 'categoryfilter' in element {store: [ { productname: "monitor", price: 1500, quantity: 5, categoryfilter: "Monitors", description: "tests", timestamp: "December 24th 2021, 1:39:36 pm", _id: ObjectId('61c55d687d8ff305de3ed044') } ]}

Comment: I also tried to add $ operator and the error still the same like this - MongoServerError: Cannot create field 'categoryfilter' in element {store: [ { productname: "monitor", price: 1500, quantity: 5, categoryfilter: "Monitors", description: "tests", timestamp: "December 24th 2021, 1:39:36 pm", _id: ObjectId('61c55d687d8ff305de3ed044') } ]}