# Mongoose update using dot notation and $ operator

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a object that I want to update using findOneAndUpdate but it seems it's not working..
I already tried to use $ operator but it's not working but once I remove $ operator the call shows error of.

```
MongoServerError: Cannot create field 'categoryfilter' in element {store: [ { productname: "monitor", price: 1500, quantity: 5, categoryfilter: "Monitors", description: "tests", timestamp: "December 24th 2021, 1:39:36 pm", _id: ObjectId('61c55d687d8ff305de3ed044'), 0: { categoryfilter: "Monitors", description: "testsss", price: 1500, productname: "monitor", quantity: 5, timestamp: "December 24th 2021, 1:39:36 pm" } } ]}    at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\gamex\Desktop\my files\goldenwell\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:467:30)   
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:376:20)   
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\gamex\Desktop\my files\goldenwell\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)        
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\gamex\Desktop\my files\goldenwell\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:745:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)       
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9) {
  operationTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1640325515, i: 17 }),
  ok: 0,
  code: 28,
  codeName: 'PathNotViable',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1640325515, i: 17 }),
    signature: {
      hash: new Binary(Buffer.from("c08511e0a3727ac6636aa2c56b4587cfcf0c2396", "hex"), 0),    
      keyId: new Long("7013342858887299079")   
    }
  }
}
```

here's my Schema I created using mongoose.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const OwnerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        require: true,
        type: String,
    },
    password: {
        require: true,
        type: String,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
    store: [
        {
            productname: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
              },
            price: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
              },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
              },
            categoryfilter: {
              type: String,
              required: true
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
              },
            imageBase64: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
              },
            timestamp: {
              type: String,
              required: true,
            }
            
        }
    ]
});

const OwnerModels = mongoose.model('OwnerModels', OwnerSchema);

export default OwnerModels;
```

here's my query for update. I've tried to use $ operator but it seems no use at all so removed it.

```
export const updateProduct = async (req,res) => {

    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Invalid ID' });

        await OwnerModels.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': id, store:{ $elemMatch: { productname: req.body.store[0].productname }}},
            {$set: 
                {
                    "store.productname": req.body.store[0].productname,
                    "store.price": req.body.store[0].price,
                    "store.quantity": req.body.store[0].quantity,
                    "store.categoryfilter": req.body.store[0].categoryfilter,
                    "store.description": req.body.store[0].description,
                    "store.timestamp": req.body.store[0].timestamp 
                }
            }, 
            {new: true, safe: true, upsert: true}, (error, response) => {
                if(error){
                    console.log(error)
                }else{
                    console.log(response)
                }
            }
            );

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json(error)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your `OwnerModels` schema?

Comment: please check my schema... I updated the post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose delete other objects after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70463985/mongoose-delete-other-objects-after-update)

Comment: It didn't work .. maybe I'll try to remove that $elemMatch and use arrayFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `store` is an array, mongodb cannot know which element in `store` to update by your `{ $set: { 'store.categoryfilter': ... } }` statement.

The `$elemMatch` query is just for query filter at document level, it will not pick the specific `store` element out to update.

The right choice is to use [arrayFilter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#std-label-findAndModify-arrayFilters) in update statement

Comment: Maybe I'll try to remove $elemMatch and use arrayFilter. I'm kinda new to mongo queries and this is my first time of trying to edit specific object inside my array store.

Answer (score 1):

Try to retrieve the `OwnerModel` with a `findByid` and then update the `store` array using the `push` method.
You will need to save the updated object using the `save` method.

```
const owner = await OwnerModels.findByid(id);
if (!owner) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Owner not found" });
}
owner.store.push(req.body.store);
await owner.save();

res.status(200).json({ message: "Updated" })
```

Finally, you may want to add a `default` value to the `imageBase64` field, since I don't see it listed in your body params:

```
imageBase64: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: ""
},
```